# nodmraid and Installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside with Windows 10 on my Asus X555U.

I've installed Ubuntu many times before in the past so I expected it to be a breeze (clearly it wasn't). After preparing the installation to begin (where the installer shows that you are connected to power/the internet) I click continue and get the ubi-partman exit code 10 error. After a bit of google-fu it seems that it's possible it's caused by the way my HDD is partitioned. Normally I let the Ubuntu installer do the disk management so this caught me off guard. In any event, I found that selecting the 'nodmraid' boot option from the advanced welcome screen would solve my problems...

Now here's the problem: apparently by default grub2 doesn't have that splash screen that allows you to pull up the advanced menu. I've tried pressing escape, shift, it's just not gonna happen.

Furthermore, I've attempted to modify the .iso installer such that `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` is a nonzero value and then reburn it to a new disk but the new disks are not bootable.

Can anybody help me? I'm losing my mind over here. I appreciate all the help I can get.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to say very quickly, you should **NEVER** modify the ISO! Anyway, the solution:
If you can still boot into Windows, Destroy the partition(s) on which you installed Ubuntu. Unfortunatly, this is the only way I know of to get the error to go away. Boot back into your installation media. Go into **try Ubuntu without installing**. On the dash, search "disks" and choose the program that matches. Select your main disk and look at the "new partition" button (+) under your disk's graph. If this is greyed out, you cannot install Ubuntu unless you change your partition table (it's a crazy Microsoft thing). If it is not, manually make two partitions (as big as you wish), one Ext4, and the other SWAP. Now you must look at the other partitions. Partition 1 should appear as either "Microsoft Basic Data" or "xData". Partition 2 should appear as "vFat", "Bootable Partition", or "Microsoft Boot Data". Nothing else matters at this point. If something didn't match, then Ubuntu probably won't install unless you format the disk in GPT. If everything matched, then **keep disks open** and start the installer. It should work now that it has something to scan.

This may not work, however, because with things like this you have to specifically know the machine (which is hard when you can't see the computer yourself!). If it still doesn't work, let me know, as I am very willing to help.